# Converting value type array to reference type array

Tags: c#, arrays, object, reflection, covariance

I need to write an exception class that takes a message and an info object of any type (usually anonymous object).

I have the following code:

```
public SpecialException(string message, object info) : this(message)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(info.GetType()))
    {
        object value = property.GetValue(info);
        string valueStr = value.GetType().IsArray ? (value as IEnumerable<object>).Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((x, y) => $"{x}, {y}") : value.ToString();
        sb.AppendLine($"{property.Name} = {valueStr}");
    }
    Info = sb.ToString();
}
```

The problem is, this code does not work when one of the anonymous object's properties is an array of value-typed items since they do not inherit object and this type of covariance cannot work with them.

What I tried, but found either not to work or inelegant:

- Using a `Dictionary<string, object>` - Cannot override the `Add` method
- Using the `IDictionary<string, object>` interface - Do not want to implement all of the interface's methods for a simple exception
- Using an `ExpandoObject` and `dynamic` keyword - Will run into the same problems as the code above
- Serializing to JSON using `dynamic` and Newtonsoft JSON - Do not want a dependancy on a third-party library (or the Web DLL)

I assume there is an elegant way (probably using reflection) to achieve this, perhaps by somehow iterating through the array. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: `(value as IEnumerable<object>)` -> `(value as IEnumerable).Cast<object>()`

Comment: value types do actually inherit from `object`

Comment: How does it not work? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: They do, but you can only box/unbox them. Polymorphism will not work. I get an `ArgumentNullException` for some reason. Running it in immediate window creates an internal debugger error.

Comment: PetSerAI suggestion should work. `(value as IEnumerable<object>)` is returning `null` since `value` may not implement `IEnumerable<object>` unless it is `object[]`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: That worked. If you want, you can post that as the answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variance does not work for value types. So that, value type array can not be casted to `IEnumerable<object>`, but it still can be casted to non-generic `IEnumerable` interface. After that you can call `Cast<object>()` extension method to get `IEnumerable<object>` instance.

```
((IEnumerable)value).Cast<object>()
```